# Finding integration using Cauchy Residue formula

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Compute the residues at all the singularities of the function $tanh(z)$, and compute the integral
$\int_C tanh(z)$ where C is the circle of radius 12 centred at $z_0 = 0$.

attempt:singularities are $z: cosh(z)=0$ i.e. $z = i\pi(2k +1)/2$ , $k \;    \epsilon \; Z$ Now we have calculate the residue of $tanh(z)$ at $-7i\pi/2$ ,$-5i\pi/2$,$-3i\pi/2$,$-i\pi/2$,$i\pi/2$,$3i\pi/2$,$5i\pi/2$, and $7i\pi/2$
then the value of the integral is $2\pi i.$(sum of the residue).
problem can't able to find the residue

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
If $\lim_{z \to a}(z-a)f(z)$ exists and is finite then it is equal to the residue of $f$ in $a$.